# com.android.incallui: not syncing the contacts

Tags: contacts

I have xaiomi redmi 7S.

I have seen the application used for calling is `com.android.incallui`

I added some contacts to it. But they are not syncing to the google account.

Comment: That app doesn't store contacts. Contacts Storage does. As for sync, have you enabled sync for contacts under Settings > Accounts >your account? Make sure to do "sync now" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding Contacts in Android is a very easy thing if you have been using android for a couple of time. The OS manages contacts by working with a few apps. Some which are physical and some which are non physical on the App Drawer.

We have Contacts Storage, a core app that is used to manage a contact database in the system. By adding, deleting and editing Contacts as commanded by Contact User Apps

We have Contacts Provider which queries names of Contacts from the Contacts Storage app or any other Contact Repository. Sometimes this app can Cache Contacts so as to real-timely process Call and Message identification rapidly

We have the Contacts App that can be seen in the application drawer that is used to present the Contacts database alongside with formal editing ways a human can understand instead of the traditional query languages

What's funny, none of these apps is responsible for synchronization of Contacts to Google or anywhere. This is where we have wrapper apps that work across the system and Google to ensure that a well maintained active sync exists

We then have Google Contacts Sync which synchronizes them from the Contacts app and transports them to Google servers and also restores them upon Mail login on a new device. As long as all those apps exist. Contact services work well.

You should note that Phone Services are also Closely related to Contact Services. This is where we find Phone Storage which maintains a call log database. Telephony Provider which offers the native calling service, Phone which shows you calls and gives you options to do on a number and also maintain a physical call history, and Calling Framework (in-Call UI) which themes the calling screen.

Note `com.android.incallui` is not responsible for any synchronization of Contacts to Google

Back to the topic. If you don't see any synchronization to google, ensure Contacts sync setting is active, ensure power saving is off to help in freeing background services like sync and to be sure, force a 'sync now'

if you don't see a name of a person in a call whose name exists in Contacts even though I'm sure `com.android.incallui` (Phone) should be having such access by default. Only a few phones don't treat it so and if you find it needs manual permission confirmation try to allow permissions from app settings and if none of those works wrap issues up and  reset the device and you'll start over again